# Dependency injection of service within Angular component library

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am creating an Angular component library. Each component is set up to be its own sub-entry point. One of these components is a simple button (@myorg/ui/button). The button injects a service from @myorg/ui/theme. The library builds without issue and I can use the button component in a demo app within the same workspace.

The problem is when I import my library into an Angular app in a separate workspace. When I try to build the consumer app that uses the button, an error is thrown in the imported button:

Cannot find module '@myorg/ui/theme' or it's corresponding type declarations.

import { ThemeService } from "@myorg/ui/theme";

I'm not sure what I need to do in order my library's button to properly use a service.

Comment: Seems like the Linker is doing something wrong. Can you test the import with a relative path? Like`import { something } from '../../<foo>'; `? Otherwise you could try to have a look at [Paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) in the `tsConfig`.

Comment: If I try to use a relative file path, the library does not compile:
`error TS6059: File '<PATH>/dev/ui/projects/connect/ui/theme/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '<PATH>\dev\connect-ui-kit-angular\projects\connect\ui\button'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

3 import { ThemeService } from "../../theme";`

Comment: Paths look like this:
`"paths": {
  "@myorg/ui/*": ["projects/myorg/ui/*", "projects/myorg/ui/"],
  "@myorg/ui": ["dist/myorg/ui/*", "dist/myorg/ui"]
},`

Comment: update-- you are right in that it is something weird with the Linker. When I packed it up as a tarball and installed it that way in the new project, everything works as intended

Comment: I once had that problem and I solved it by placing everything inside one module / library, using relative paths. It's not the greatest solution but it does its job.